# How to prevent a storyboard from playing automatically when window loads? I am not able to do it

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, mouseevent, blend

I have 4 storyboards with some animation.
What I want is to prevent the storyboards from playing automatically when the window is loaded. I want them to play only if the mouse is clicked within the window.
I tried the following for one storyboard:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.target2animation_BeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Stop();

    }

private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.target2animation_BeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

It did not work. It played once when the window loaded. I even tried Freeze, Pause instead of Stop. Still didn't work.

However, the storyboard always started from the beginning if I clicked, so mouseclick event is working.

Please help!

This is the code of target2animate storyboard (created via expression blend)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="target2animation" RepeatBehavior="0:0:10">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="35">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Springiness="5" Oscillations="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="-6">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Oscillations="2" Springiness="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="3">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Springiness="5" Oscillations="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="txbTarget2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="35">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="2" Springiness="5"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="-5">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Oscillations="2" Springiness="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="txbTarget2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="4">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Oscillations="2" Springiness="5"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.3" Value="5">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ElasticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" Oscillations="2" Springiness="2"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Try calling `this.target2animation_BeginStoryboard.Storyboard.Begin();` on `UserControl_Loaded` function.

Comment: Can you post your complete code please? i mean, including  where target2animation_BeginStoryboard is declared.

Comment: That code is really really long...
I am posting the code of only target2animation instead.

Comment: @cDima it didn't work. I want the storyboard NOT to start on window load.

Comment: The question is why do you have something like `target2animation_BeginStoryboard` at all? It seems to be a BeginStoryboard in an EventTrigger, but you haven't shown us what it is.

Comment: If you just include the BeginStoryboard element we could probably have this all wrapped up...

Comment: yes. agree with *Clemens* and *GlenThomas.* Please post where the BeginStoryboard element is included.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I just did this using Blend. In triggers, under UserControl_Loaded event there were these storyboards with begin().
I just removed them and created another event UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown and called the storyboards inside this with begin().
This solved the problem. Doing this via the coding way was really complicated.
Thankyou :)