# How to prevent a storyboard from playing automatically when page loads?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

This issue doesn't seem to have any cause. There is no `Storyboard.Begin()` called anywhere in code (searched with a 'Find all' in current project) and no triggers as far as can be seen.

Using `Storyboard.Stop()` in `Page_Loaded` event for every single Storyboard present fixes this issue but it seems more like a hack than a solution.
What causes this behaviour and how can it be fixed?

The similar issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905954/how-to-prevent-a-storyboard-from-playing-automatically-when-window-loads-i-am-n) has a solution but it does not apply in this case: not using Blend

My code is as follows:

```
    <Page.Resources>
       [...]
       <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StartButtonTranslateAndShrinkStoryboard">
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="0x">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                                 From="0" To="140" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                 From="0" To="300" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                                 From="3" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                                 From="3" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
       [...]
    </Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put it in the `<BeginStoryboard>` tags, that is a *trigger* that starts the storyboard. You can assign the name of the storyboard (in your case `StartButtonTranslateAndShrinkStoryboard`) to the storyboard itself instead of the trigger and it should work.

```
<Page.Resources>
   [...]
        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="0x"  x:Name="StartButtonTranslateAndShrinkStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                             From="0" To="140" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                             From="0" To="300" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)"
                             From="3" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="StartButtonTransform"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"
                             From="3" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
   [...]
</Page.Resources>
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.beginstoryboard):

> A trigger action that begins a Storyboard. **Not commonly used.**

Comment: While this was the solution and fixed my issue I still wonder why `<BeginStoryboard>` triggered if it was in `<Page.Resources>`